# Wordpress Plugin - how to add_menu_page callback with arguments

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a view renderer for my plugin.

```
class plg{
public function __construct() {
    add_menu_page( 'FooMenu', 'FooMenuAnuncios', 'manage_options', 'dglfoo', array($this, "render"), plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'images/icon-menu.png', 4  );
}

public function render($view_name){
    $html = '<div class="wrap">';
    ob_start();
    include_once(WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/plugins/myPlugin/templates/'.$view_name'.php');
    $html .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $html .= '</div>';
    echo $html;
  }
}
```

It is obvious that I want to pass the view name to each menu, something like `array($this, "render('viewname')")` instead of `array($this, "render")`. I know this example would throw an error, but what I want is to find a possible way to get this.

Comment: Your answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/16447

Comment: Thanks a lot, I couldn't find anything